# Fastest way to concatenate an integer into a string

Tags: java, string, type-conversion

I have an object that on initialisation it takes in a string to identify its name.

```
String name = "MyObject" + Integer.toString(objectNum);
object = new Object(name);
```

In the example above the name follows a convention such that an integer is concatenated with a string "MyObject". A colleague complained that the way I wrote this code is actually terrible from a performance perspective because of the int to string conversion. The number is received as an int and there's nothing I can do about that. The object parameter MUST take in a string. How can I make this quicker? Would using string format help?

Comment: `"MyObject" + objectNum`. Focus on readability.

Comment: If you want quick, don't do a whole bunch of string operations and use Java. Don't worry about premature optimization. Make the code maintainable first.

Comment: If you use a decent IDE (e.g. I just looked in intellij), it tells you to use `"MyObject" + objectNum`.

Comment: String name = "MyObject" + objectNum

Comment: "A colleague complained that the way I wrote this code is actually terrible from a performance perspective" you should ask the colleague to explain. I agree with them, but if they are going to have such a strong opinion as to describe it as "terrible", they should be able to back that up with something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
"MyObject" + objectNum
```

is best. `objectNum` is automatically effectively converted to a `String`.

Focus on readability, let Java worry about the best way to concatenate it.

---

The performance problem with `"MyObject" + Integer.toString(objectNum)` is that it explicitly creates a `String` from the `int`, and then concatenates it to the preceding `String`. It tends to be compiled to something like:

```
new StringBuilder("MyObject").append(Integer.toString(objectNum)).toString()
```

Which is... a working approach.

But, `StringBuilder` has `append(int)`, which is able to do things more efficiently if it knows the parameter is an `int`. `"MyObject" + objectNum` still becomes something like:

```
new StringBuilder("MyObject").append(objectNum).toString()
```

which just avoids creating the `String` for `objectNum`.

---

With all that said, the JIT could well recognize the `"MyObject" + Integer.toString(objectNum)` pattern, and execute it effectively like `"MyObject" + objectNum` (or vice versa, ofc, if it determines that is more efficient), so there could be no practical performance difference.

Given that, you should use the form which is easier to read, and just trust that the JIT will do its thing and execute the code as fast as it can be executed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say your code is fine as it is from a performance perspective.
The "MyObject" literal will be interned and then just reused, and every time you assign "name" you create a new string anyway, so I don't really see how that could be made to run that much faster. (Maybe storing objectNum in the object instead of name, and then only concatenating if you want to print the whole identifier? I guess you'd save a few femtoseconds that way...)

Personally, I'd use this approach (mainly for readability, and it's not the fastest in terms of execution):
String name = String.format("MyObject%d", objectNum);

Comment: `String.format` will almost certainly be slower than straight concatenation, because it has to do lots of work to parse the format string on each execution (even though it's a literal), and then build up the result; way more than the work done by a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: When looking purely at performance, you're right. I edited my answer to better explain my suggestion.